# Must use *unicode* string as text to tag, while tagging with TreeTagger?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, nlp, treetagger

From [TreeTagger's website](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) I created a directory and downloaded the specified files. Then [treetaggerwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/treetaggerwrapper/2.0.6), thus from the [documentation](https://treetaggerwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) I tried to test and try how to tag some text as follows:

```
In [40]:

import treetaggerwrapper

tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en')

tags = tagger.TagText("This is a very short text to tag.")

print tags
```

Then I got the following warnings:

```
WARNING:TreeTagger:Abbreviation file not found: english-abbreviations
WARNING:TreeTagger:Processing without abbreviations file.
ERROR:TreeTagger:Must use *unicode* string as text to tag, not <type 'str'>.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TreeTaggerError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-37b912126580> in <module>()
      1 import treetaggerwrapper
      2 tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en')
----> 3 tags = tagger.TagText("This is a very short text to tag.")
      4 print tags

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/treetaggerwrapper.pyc in TagText(self, text, numlines, tagonly, prepronly, tagblanks, notagurl, notagemail, notagip, notagdns, encoding, errors)
   1236         return self.tag_text(text, numlines=numlines, tagonly=tagonly,
   1237                  prepronly=prepronly, tagblanks=tagblanks, notagurl=notagurl,
-> 1238                  notagemail=notagemail, notagip=notagip, notagdns=notagdns)
   1239 
   1240     # --------------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/treetaggerwrapper.pyc in tag_text(self, text, numlines, tagonly, prepronly, tagblanks, notagurl, notagemail, notagip, notagdns, nosgmlsplit)
   1302             # Raise exception now, with an explicit message.
   1303             logger.error("Must use *unicode* string as text to tag, not %s.", type(text))
-> 1304             raise TreeTaggerError("Must use *unicode* string as text to tag.")
   1305 
   1306         if isinstance(text, six.text_type):

TreeTaggerError: Must use *unicode* string as text to tag.
```

Where do I download the abbreviation file for english and spanish languages?, and how can I install correctly treetaggerwrapper?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method only takes unicode strings  add a `u`  to your string to make it a *unicode string*:

```
tags = tagger.TagText(u"This is a very short text to tag.")
```

`"This is a very short text to tag."` is a *str type*, once you add the `u` it is unicode:

```
In [12]: type("This is a very short text to tag.")
Out[12]: str

In [13]: type(u"This is a very short text to tag.")
Out[13]: unicode
```

If you were taking the str from another source you would need to decode:

```
In [15]: s = "This is a very short text to tag."

In [16]: type(s)
Out[16]: str

In [17]: type(s.decode("utf-8"))
Out[17]: unicode
```

The tagging scripts can be downloaded [here](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/data/tagger-scripts.tar.gz)

Comment: Thanks for the help, on the other hand I still get the same warning: `WARNING:TreeTagger:Abbreviation file not found: english-abbreviations
WARNING:TreeTagger:Processing without abbreviations file.
`. Any idea of how to specify the path or download scuh files?.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: No worries,, I added a link for the tagging scripts, did you install using the .sh file?